# Find line and column number in the text file using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the `line` and `column` number when the string exact matches in the file. Then I can able to get the `line number` and not `column number`.

Need to find `\amp` in the below string:

```
$str = '\begin{document}
    \title{Testing}
    It is important that the final model or models should make sense
    physically: at a minimum, this usually means that interactions should
    not be included without main effects nor higher-degree polynomial
    terms without their lower-degree relatives. Furthermore, if the model
    is to be used as a summary of the findings of one out of several
    studies bearing on the same phenomenon, main effects would usually be
    included whether significant or not.

    \begin{align}\label{equilibrium-disp-cyl}
    &G\left( {{\nabla ^{2}}{u_{r}} - \frac{2}{{{r^{2}}}}\frac{{\partial
{u_{\theta} }}}{{\partial \theta }} - \frac{{{u_{r}}}}{{{r^{2}}}}}
\right) \nonumber\\
\frac{1}{r}\frac{{\partial {u_{\theta} \amp}}}{{\partial \theta }} +
)\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{{\partial \theta }}\left(
{\frac{{\partial {u_{r}}}}{{\partial r}} + \frac{{{u_{r}}}}{r} +
&G{\nabla ^{2}}{u_{z}} + ( {\lambda + G} )\frac{\partial }{{\partial
\end{align}
some para text continues....
    \begin{align}\label{equilibrium-disp-cyl}
&G\left( {{\nabla ^{2}}{u_{r}} - \frac{2}{{{r^{2}}}}\frac{{\partial
{u_{\theta} }}}{{\partial \theta }} - \frac{{{u_{r}}}}{{{r^{2}}}}}
\right) \nonumber\\
\frac{1}{r}\frac{{\partial {u_{\theta}}}}{{\partial \theta }} +
)\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{{\partial \theta }}\left(
{\frac{{\partial {u_{r}}}}{{\partial r}} + \frac{{{u_{r}}}}{r} +
&G{\nabla ^{2}}{u_{z}} + ( {\lambda + G} \amp )\frac{\partial }{{\partial
\end{align}
some para text continues....
    \begin{align}\label{equilibrium-disp-cyl}
&G\left( {{\nabla ^{2}}{u_{r}} - \frac{2}{{{r^{2}}}}\frac{{\partial
{u_{\theta} }}}{{\partial \theta }} - \amp \frac{{{u_{r}}}}{{{r^{2}}}}}
\right) \nonumber\\
\frac{1}{r}\frac{{\partial {u_{\theta}}}}{{\partial \theta }} +
)\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{{\partial \theta }}\left(
{\frac{{\partial {u_{r}}}}{{\partial r}} + \frac{{{u_{r}}}}{r} +
&G{\nabla ^{2}}{u_{z}} + ( {\lambda + G} \amp )\frac{\partial }{{\partial
\end{align}
';
```

My Code:

```
my $_pres = ();
while($str=~m/\\begin\{align\}((?:(?!\\end\{align\}).)*)\\end\{align\}/sg)
{
    $_pres = $`; my $nolabel = $&;
    if($nolabel=~m/\\amp/i)
    {
        my $nwpre = $`; $newpre = $_pres.$nwpre;

        my ($line) = ($newpre =~s/\n/\n/g)+1;
        print "L: $line - Found amp...!!!\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 L: 8 - Found amp...!!!
 L: 21 - Found amp...!!!
 L: 26 - Found amp...!!!
```

Expected output:

```
 L: 7:nn - \\amp command found ...!!!
```

Could someone please guide me to get the `column` number and it would be appreciated also.

Comment: What is the match for `\begin` and `\end` for?

Comment: Sorry @Borodin. I couldn't understand you question please.

Comment: @ssr102: Your question asks for the line and character numbers within the file, but your code searches for `\begin{align}` ... `\end{align}` subsequences and works with those instead. The result is a line number *within the subsequence*, not within the file. Why don't you just find all occurrences of `\amp`?

Comment: @Borodin: Yes you are correct. I need the line number and column number for the whole file wherever the `\amp` matches.

Comment: How did this go?  Any feedback?  Can we offer more explanations?

Comment: @ssr1012  I don't understand how that changed your question.  You still want the line number and the column number.

Comment: @zdim: There is a concern while getting the line number with full file content and a portion of the content.

Comment: @ssr1012 Right, got it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that the `\\begin\{align\}` and `\\end\{align\}` patterns are there to locate such passages (Latex's `align` environment) in a larger body of text.

Once you got that, break the rest into lines and finding `\amp`'s location is then easy

```
use warnings;
use strict;

# ADDED another "\amp", to the line before last
my $str = '\begin{align}\label{equilibrium-disp-cyl}  
    ... [ suppressed for brevity ]    
\right) = 0, \amp
\end{align}
';

while ($str =~ m/\\begin\{align\} (.*?) \\end\{align\}/sgx)
{
    my @lines = split /\n/, $1; 
    for my $i (0..$#lines)
    {
        my $line = $lines[$i];

        if ($line =~ /(\\amp)/i) 
        {
            print  "Found '$1' -- ";
            printf "Line number: %3d, match start: %2d, match end: %2d\n",
                $i+1, $-[0], $+[0];
        }
    }
}
```

This uses `@-` (`@LAST_MATCH_START`) and `@+` (`@LAST_MATCH_END`) arrays, which give offsets of the start and end of last successful submatches.  See [Regex related variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions).  As there is only one match I use the first element, `$-[0]`.

I use the simple `(.*?)` instead of an unneeded negative lookahead in the middle.

With your whole string restored (plus the extra `\amp`), the above prints

```
Found '\amp' -- Line number:   7, match start: 39, match end: 43
Found '\amp' -- Line number:  14, match start: 13, match end: 17
```

where I've added another `\amp` on the line-before-last, for a better test.

---

Clarification: We need the line number in the whole file and the column in the line where `\amp` is found, within the Latex's `align` environment (given by `\begin{align}`, `\end{align}`).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'doc.tex';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>)
{
    if (/\\begin\{align\}/ .. /\\end\{align\}/)
    {   
        if (/(\\amp)/i) 
        {   
            print  "Found '$1' -- ";
            printf "Line number: %3d, match start: %2d, match end: %2d\n",
                $., $-[0], $+[0];
        }
    }
}
```

where the `if` statement uses the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to ensure that the `/\\amp/` match is performed within the `align` environment only. The [`$.` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$.) gives us the line number, and the use of `@-` and `@+` is the same as explained above.

With the file `doc.tex` having the contents shown in the question, this prints

```
Found '\amp' -- Line number:  15, match start: 39, match end: 43
Found '\amp' -- Line number:  28, match start: 41, match end: 45
Found '\amp' -- Line number:  33, match start: 38, match end: 42
Found '\amp' -- Line number:  38, match start: 41, match end: 45
```

which I can confirm as correct locations in that text.

Comment: @ssr1012 In the light of your updated question, this gives you the line number and the column where the pattern is found (either pattern's beginning or its end) so it's still valid?  Let me know if it is not.

Comment: No. Its only going to support the matches begin and end. I want to fetch the full file and get the line and column number for the matches.

Comment: @ssr1012 I added another solution for your updates.  It gets the line number in the whole file (as shown in the question), and the column number within the line.

Comment: Expected output matched awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Add an index check;

```
my $index = index($str, '\\amp');
print "L: $line:$index - \\amp command found...!!!\n";
```

however it's not enough to get 42,

```
[root@cal180 ~]# perl test.pl
L: 7:362 - \amp command found...!!!
```

Sounds like you may also want to parse brackets?